# Rails batch object creation for fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

I have a big list of record (something like 20, could be more) with a has_many :through relations, which is a bit complicate and it looks ugly on yml. Factory_girl doesn't seems to give me the simplistic ability to just create the fixture with a AR based script (it's a lot shorter that way) any good recommendation on what I could do?

Answer (score 2):

Don't monkey patch! Use Factory Girl! (she's sweet):

```
Factory.define(:user) do |t|
   t.factory { |a| a.assocation(:factory) }
end

Factory.define(:factory) do |t|
  t.name  "Test Factory"
end
```

In our specs do this:

```
before(:each) do 
  @factory = Factory(:factory)
  20.times do
    Factory(:user, :factory => @factory)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use Factory Girl's Sequences to generate unique factory names, or add user names and the like easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could open up your model again in your factories file and add a method to create the test records. Something like:

```
class User 
  after_create :create_records_for_testing
  def create_records_for_testing
    # code to create records
  end
end
```

Of course that could cause confusion down the road because the model you're testing doesn't behave the same as the model you're using in your app. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: This is very evil! You could change other pars as well in your User model and break every test in the system (or make them all pass when they shouldn't). Don't monkey-patch our models for testing!

Comment: A better idea might be to use something like this patch for Factory Girl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506556/hasmany-while-respecting-build-strategy-in-factorygirl